# Export a popup from Kony Visualizer V8 and import it to Kony Visualizer V9

Tags: popup, visualizer, temenos-quantum

I have a popup in code written in Kony visualizer V8, I want to export all of them and import it to Kony Visualizer V9.

**Note**: Kony Visualizer V9 doesn't support the normal popups and I don't need to create it from scratch.

This is the popup's image inside the Visualiser V8:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar requirement recently and as V9 doesn't support HBOX or VBOX, created a component for popup and used that in UI. After changing all popups to components you can upgrade from v8 to v9 without issues.

Also do not use masters as that is also not compatible with V9.
You can use components and reuse them for popups wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Gone thru the same situation before. Found that HBOX, VBOX and few other widgets which are used in the old versions are deprecated in the recent versions. Hence all the old widgets should be updated to the latest equivalent widgets.

If the project is mobile application then Temenos has an upgrade tool which will help you in making the changes to the project and upgrade it. But if the project is of Desktop web then we need to manually update the widgets one by one. Once all the deprecated widgets are upgraded then export the project and import the same in latest visualizer.